# Confused about Power Functions M-motor 8883 and 8293

Tags: technic, power-functions, motor, creator

Is the motor that comes with the Technic power functions motor set (8293) and the stand alone motor 8883 the same?  We have just built the LEGO Creator 10261 roller coaster set and it specifies a 8883 with 88000 battery box.  Not sure if I have bought the wrong thing with the 8293 set which is on its way.  Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both items contain the same M-Motor part.